# How to start Nextjs application with NewRelic agent?

Tags: next.js, newrelic

I have installed Newrelic agent on my Nextjs app.
So far I have done the following on my nextjs app:

`npm install @newrelic/next`

I then copied the newrelic.js file to my root folder.  I added my license key and my app name in that file.

I also update the package.json file with newrelic in the profile to run:

```
"scripts": {    
    "dev-k8": "NODE_OPTIONS='-r @newrelic/next' next dev -p 3000", 
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

I then start my Nextjs app as :
`npm run dev-k8`

It starts fine.  But I don't see any trace or events in my NewRelic for the browser app.

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0):

This official article, [How to monitor a Next.js application](https://newrelic.com/blog/how-to-relic/nextjs-monitor-application-data), can help you set up the New Relic for your Next.js application.

You can refer to this repo, [newrelic-nextjs-integration](https://github.com/newrelic-experimental/newrelic-nextjs-integration), it is an example to integrate Next.js with New Relic.

Comment: I followed their instructions.  However, their example does something else.  I will have to try the example and see.